# I clicked a Grabify link, is my whole life in danger?

Tags: ip

I clicked a Grabify link from Discord as I did not know what a Grabify link is. When I found out it was an IP logger, I panicked. And I already tried rebooting my wi-fi but the IP didn't change, and he said if I asked him a question he would call me via phone as he can find it out from my IP.  What should I do, am I under threat, is my life threatened? I can remove my data from Grabify but I'm afraid he already saved my IP. Can he track my online activities, can he harm my computer and can he hack my computer? Is my whole life in danger?

Comment: every website you visit knows your IP, otherwise it couldn't send you the page. you can also pretty much guess IPs, since many/most of the combos are in-use.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not in danger. Knowing your IP means an attacker knows *roughly* your location, such as "You live in New York City", or "You live in northern Australia". That's pretty much the level of information an attacker has.

They don't know your address, phone number, or are able to hack you. It's an empty threat designed to cause you to panic and have you comply.

Just ignore it, block the guy on Discord and move on.

Comment: It cannot check my files right?

Comment: @BillyForter No. As I stated, it's an empty threat.

Comment: so like everything likes spying my camera, calling me via phone are all just a empty threat?

Comment: @BillyForter How do you know someone is spying on you? Do you have concrete evidence for that?

Comment: My avast keep popping out that "Your computer is on risk" or something like that Im afraid someone is spying my computer and camera using some kind of spyware that can track my computer activity and camera

Comment: @BillyForter You are jumping to conclusions. Does Avast say *why* your computer is at risk? AV software likes to engage in fear-mongering to validate your decision to use AV software. I ask you again, what **concrete evidence of spying** do you have?

Comment: Nothing really, Im sorry, I just dont know much about IP related things. I just overpanic.

Comment: Also, when I click that popup where Avast keep saying my computer at risk just redirect me into a premium subscription page. I really dont know if something is happening on my computer or its just to engage me to buy the premium subscription. Im sorry I dont really know what to do, Im sorry if this is bothering you.

Comment: So everything is just a empty thread to cause me panic?

Comment: @BillyForter It is exactly as I said. Avast is trying to convince you to buy more expensive stuff. That's all there is to it. No one is spying on you.